# How can I shorten an array?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wanted to create a function that deletes from an array of segments the ones that are longer than a given number, by freeing the memory I don't need anymore. The problem is that the function I've created frees also all the memory allocated after the given point. How can I limit it, so that it frees just one pointer without compromising the others?
Here is the code I've written so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
  double x1;
  double y1;
  double x2;
  double y2;
} Segment;

double length(Segment* s)
{
  return sqrt(pow(s->x1 - s->x2, 2) + pow(s->y1 - s->y2, 2));
}

// HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
void delete_longer(Segment* as[], int n, double max_len)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(length(as[i]) > max_len)
    {
      as[i] = NULL; // Those two lines should be swapped, but the problem remains
      free(as[i]);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  const int SIZE = 5;
  Segment** arr = (Segment**)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(Segment*));
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    arr[i] = (Segment*)malloc(sizeof(Segment));
  }

  srand(time(0));

  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    arr[i]->x1 = rand() % 100;
    arr[i]->x2 = rand() % 100;
    arr[i]->y1 = rand() % 100;
    arr[i]->y2 = rand() % 100;
    printf("Lungezza: %d\n", (int)length(arr[i]));
  }

  delete_longer(arr, SIZE, 80);

  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE && arr[i]; i++)
  {
    printf("Lunghezza 2: %d\n", (int)length(arr[i]));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must first `free(as[i])` and the set it to `as[i]=NULL;`. Otherwise you try to free a null pointer, which could be undefined behavior.

Comment: Your code has the order backwards.  `as[i] = NULL; free(as[i]);` is the wrong order.  You should free the current value, then assign NULL.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Freeing a NULL pointer is well defined, but pointless.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thanks. Will try to remember :-)

Comment: Your `length` function must of course be able to handle a NULL argument.

Comment: Your `for` loop stops at the first null element. That is not what you want. So not all the memory after it is deleted, you just don't print it.

Comment: I don't often wear a language lawyer hat, but 7.20.3.1 of n1256 states: `The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs.`

Comment: I originally freed the array and than I set it to NULL, but it did't work so I thought if would be helpful to swap the two... but now that I think of it it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main problems:

In the delete function you write:

```
  as[i] = NULL;
  free(as[i]);
```

This is the wrong order. You must first free the memory and then set the element to null. But note that this is not the cause of your perceived problem, it only causes a memory leak (i.e. the memory of `as[i]` becomes inaccessible). You should write:

```
  free(as[i]);
  as[i] = NULL;
```

Your second problem is in your `for` loop, which now stops at the first null element. So not all the memory after it is deleted, you just don't print it. The loop should be for example:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
       printf("Lunghezza 2: %d\n", arr[i]?(int)length(arr[i]):0);
  }
```

<sub>Note: I agree with the discussion that `free(NULL)` may be implementation dependent in older implementations of the library function. In my personal opinion, never pass `free` a null pointer. I consider it bad practice.</sub>

Comment: Paul, it causes more than a memory leak.  If you call `free(NULL);` you run into undefined behaviour, depending on how old the `free()` implementation is.

Comment: @LuisColorado `free(NULL)` is not undefined behavior on any platform that is in active use outside of retrocomputing community, so that's a red herring. Citing C89 **4.10.3.2 The free function [...] If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs**. 1989 was 31 years ago, for crying out loud. We're not talking about C on PDP-11 here.

Comment: Is not undefined behaviour as per the last C standards, but before the concept was introduced, passing `NULL` to `free()` was not secure, and was implementation dependent (implementation of `free()`, not of any compiler/standard)  I would not rely on passing `NULL` to `free()` if I'm going to write portable code (more with the so easy workaround of checking for `NULL` before calling)  And I'm not talking about C in the PDP-11 also, but on some versions of Solaris and SCO UNIX (which is still in use in some environments)  You can write your code as you want.... but don't blame me for that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the free function should come after the instruction that sets the pointer to NULL, but that's not the main cause of the problem.
What causes the behaviour I described was the fact that the second for loop in the main stops after finding the first NULL pointer. Instead I should have written:

```c
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i])
      printf("Lunghezza 2: %d\n", (int)length(arr[i]));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change the size of an array at runtime.  The compiler assigns the memory statically, and even automatic arrays are fixed size (except if you use the last C standard, in which you can specify a different size at declaration time, but even in that case, the array size stands until the array gets out of scope).  The reason is that, once allocated, the memory of an array gets surrounded of other declarations that, being fixed, make it difficult ot use the memory otherwise.

The other alternative is to allocate the array dynamically.  You allocate a fixed number of cells, and store with the array, not only it's size, but also its capacity (the maximum amount of cell it is allow to grow)  Think that erasing an element of an array requires moving all the elements behind to the front one place, and this is in general an expensive thing to do.  If your array is filled with references to other objects, a common technique is to use `NULL` pointers on array cells that are unused, or to shift all the elements one place to the beginning.

Despite the technique you use, arrays are a very efficient way to access multiple objects of the same type, but they are difficult to shorten or enlengthen.

Finally, a common technique to handle arrays in a way you can consider them as variable length is to allocate a fixed amount of cells (initially) and if you need more memory to allocate double the space of the original (there are other approaches, like using a fibonacci sequence to grow the array) and use the size of the array and the actual capacity of it.  Only in case your array is full, you call a function that will allocate a new array of larger size, adjust the capacity, copy the elements to the new copy, and deallocate the old array.  This will work until you fill it again.

You don't post any code, so I shall do the same.  If you have some issue with some precise code, don't hesitate to post it in your question, I'll try to provide you with a working solution.